# Any way to set rmarkdown::paged_table() as the deafult way to printing table?

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto

I have seen a [tutorial](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/opts-render.html) by which one can change the way tables are printed to knitr::kable() format. Is it possible to do the same with the rmarkdown::paged_table() format, so that all tables by default will be printed in `paged_table()` format as in the `{rmarkdown}` package in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of Rmarkdown the answer offered by @VishalKatti is IMHO the way to go. For Quarto (or RMarkdown), adapting the example in the R Markdown Cookbook one option to achieve your desired result may look like so:

````
---
title: Use a custom `knit_print` method to print data frames
format: html
---

First, we define a `knit_print` method, and register it:

```{r}
knit_print.data.frame = function(x, ...) {
  res = rmarkdown::paged_table(x)
  rmarkdown:::knit_print.data.frame(res)
}

registerS3method(
  "knit_print", "data.frame", knit_print.data.frame,
  envir = asNamespace("knitr")
)
```

Now we can test this custom printing method on data frames.
Note that you no longer need to call `rmarkdown::paged_table()`
explicitly.

```{r}
head(iris)
```

```{r}
head(mtcars)
```
````

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/933 The same is addressed here. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in Quarto and the solution is to use `df-print: paged` (note df-print not df_print) in the yaml file.

Eg.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
editor: visual
format: 
   html:
     df-print: paged
---

```{r}
data.frame(
  x = 1:10,
  y = rnorm(10)
)
```
````

which results in this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Put this in the yaml.

```
output:
  html_document: 
    df_print: paged
```

Comment: Haha. Yeah. That is indeed much easier than the approach with using a customized `knit_print`. +1

Comment: yeah this works for markdown, but I am using quarto

Comment: Check out this post from RStudio Community talking about the exact same issue in Quarto. https://community.rstudio.com/t/quarto-data-frame-printing/133647

Comment: @stefan: your solution should work for Quarto.

Comment: Hej Visahl. Yeah. You are right. Will edit and undelete it.

Answer (score 1):

To complete the answer shared above, here are several ways to achieve this

### Using a printing function for **knitr**

For paged table this would be this function: (which is used internally by rmarkdown for the `df_print` feature)

```r
paged_print <- function(x, options) {
  knitr::asis_output(
    rmarkdown:::paged_table_html(x, options = attr(
      x,
      "options"
    )),
    meta = list(dependencies = rmarkdown::html_dependency_pagedtable())
  )
}
```

This is similar to the function in the other answer, it is just that `rmarkdown:::knit_print.data.frame` does more than juts handling paged tables.

Then you could register it in a document so that it is applied by default for any data.frame printing.

```
registerS3method(
  "knit_print", "data.frame", paged_print,
  envir = asNamespace("knitr")
)
```

or use it on chunk basis where you need to print a data.frame in a single value chunk. (

````markdown
```{r, render = paged_print}
iris
```
````

More on custom printing method for **knitr** [its vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/knitr/vignettes/knit_print.html)

### Using option hooks for knitr

A df_print chunk option can also be simulated this way using a [option hook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/option-hooks.html)

```r
knitr::opts_hooks$set(df_print = function(options) {
  if (options$df_print == "paged") {
    options$render = paged_print
  }
  options
})
```

this will allow something like

````r
```{r, df_print = "paged"}
iris
```

```{r}
iris
```
````

- First table will be shown as paged table
- Second table will be show as usual data.frame